# How to store persistent data without a database in .netcore API

Tags: asp.net-core, api-design

I have a dotnet core 2.0 API. I want to store the total number of requests and also the number of requests made per user. I can't store this information in the database, because the API connects to many different databases dynamically depending on what the user needs.  Also, I can't just use logging because I want to retrieve these numbers using a request in the API.

The only thing I can think of would be using a custom JSON file, and to continually update the file using middle ware. But this seems cumbersome, and I feel like there's got to be an easier way to store small amounts of permanent data. Maybe there's a nuget package someone can recommend?

Comment: Just because you're using multiple interchangeable databases doesn't mean you can't add another connection/context that is constant to store this. Also, you can always read the log source to retrieve the numbers, so logging *is* a viable option. However, as far as persistence goes, you must either use a database or a file. Anything else (i.e. memory) is *not* persistent.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you could use cache memory depending for how long you want this data to be stored.

In other case, as suggested, your only choices is a file or a database.